# A single user can't access server folders from a single computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2012, windows-domain, folder-redirection

This morning I had a domain user try to log onto his primary laptop. At logon he received a network permission error regarding his Desktop redirected folder on the server. He also received error notices about corrupted Recycle Bin for each of his redirected folders. Obviously his Desktop was blank and he couldn't get to any of his redirected folders in File Explorer due to the same permission errors.

This user was successfully reading and writing files to the server yesterday afternoon, and he was able to work from home via Offline Files yesterday evening as well without issue. But this morning it doesn't work at all.

I disabled all networking and logged in using his cached credentials, expecting the locally synced offline copies to appear. But again, I received the network errors. This time it was error code 0x80070035, The network path was not found. Even a full reboot didn't allow access to Offline Files.

Interestingly, this user is able to log on from other computers. Likewise, other users are able to log on to his laptop and access server files without issue. So it seems like the issue is directly related to his local profile on that particular machine. Unfortunately, I don't know what troubleshooting steps to take next. Ideally I'd like to restore the existing profile and somehow recover the offline files he worked on last night, which never had a chance to sync back to the server. Plan B would be to destroy the local profile and start fresh.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the offline files cache is corrupt. Rebuilding this cache would probably solve it. Note, the files are located in C:\Windows\CSC but you need to become owner to get there, which will not be good for Offline files unless you are going to rebuild it anyway.

Comment: This was a good try but didn't fix it. I'm going to have to try restoring the user profile from a known good backup. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I speak out of experience that you will have to do this, but doing it right is not easy. But getting access to the CSC files will allow you to recover files that weren't synced.